# International travel with power banks

Tags: air-travel

I checked with airlines websites about regulations on lithium battery with capacity under 100WH. They didn’t state the quantity limitation for battery with capacity less than 100WH. I am wondering if I can carry 3 of my 99WH power banks with or without special procedure? My trip are usually between US and Japan.

Answer (score 9):

Per [IATA rules](https://www.iata.org/contentassets/6fea26dd84d24b26a7a1fd5788561d6e/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf) you are allowed to carry up to 20 such power banks. They must be isolated and in your carry-on luggage.

Note that those are IATA guidelines, individual airlines are allowed to deviate from that, so you should check the airline’s rules.

Comment: I guess that would be the total number of power banks and spare batteries including such things as DSLR batteries, drone batteries and so on.